# Reduce run time in Clojure

Tags: performance, beginner, clojure

I have a task which runs sequentially. If I have hundreds of thousands of tags, it is very time consuming. Can this be modified to run the task in parallel? Works fine upto 100 tags

````
 (:require [content :as db-content]
           [impl.content-tag :as db-content-tag]
           [story :as db-story]
           [tag :as db-tag]
           [transaction :as transaction]
           [log :as log]
           [config :as config]))

(defn- find-story-ids-by-tag [tag-id]
 (map :id (db-content-tag/read-contents-by-tag-id (config/db-spec) tag-id)))

(defn- update-story [txn publisher-id story-id tag-id]
 (let [{:keys [published-json]} (db-content/find-by-id txn story-id)
       updated-tags (filter (fn [tag] (not= (:id tag) tag-id)) (:tags published-json))
       _ (db-story/update-published-json-without-timestamps txn publisher-id story-id (assoc published-json :tags updated-tags))]
   (log/info {:message "[TAG-DELETION] Updated Story Tags in Published JSON"
              :publisher-id publisher-id
              :tag-id tag-id
              :story-id story-id
              :updated-tags-json updated-tags})))

(defn- delete-tag [publisher-id tag-id]
 (let [associated-content-ids (find-story-ids-by-tag tag-id)]
   (transaction/with-transaction
     [txn (config/db-spec)]
     (do
       (when (seq associated-content-ids)
         (do
           (doseq [story-id associated-content-ids]
             (update-story txn publisher-id story-id tag-id))
           (db-content-tag/delete-batch-by-tag txn tag-id associated-content-ids)
           (log/info {:message "[TAG-DELETION] Deleted from Content Tag"
                      :publisher-id publisher-id
                      :tag-id tag-id
                      :story-ids associated-content-ids})))
       (db-tag/delete txn publisher-id tag-id)
       (log/info {:message "[TAG-DELETION] Deleted Tag"
                  :publisher-id publisher-id
                  :tag-id tag-id})))))

(defn run [publisher-id tag-ids]
 (comment run 123 [4 5 6])
 (try
   (do
     (log/info {:message "[TAG-DELETION] started"
                :publisher-id publisher-id
                :tag-ids tag-ids})
     (doseq [tag-id tag-ids] (if (db-tag/find-by-id (config/db-spec) publisher-id tag-id)
                               (delete-tag publisher-id tag-id)
                               (log/info {:message "[TAG-DELETION] Tag Not Found"
                                          :publisher-id publisher-id
                                          :tag-id tag-id})))
     (log/info {:message "[TAG-DELETION] completed"
                :publisher-id publisher-id
                :tag-ids tag-ids}))
   (catch Exception e
     (log/exception e {:message "[TAG-DELETION] errored"
                       :publisher-id publisher-id
                       :tag-ids tag-ids}))))```
````

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Do you expect a speed-up factor into the thousands from *running the task in parallel*?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [the Claypoole library](https://github.com/clj-commons/claypoole).  Sample code:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [com.climate.claypoole :as pool]
    ))

(defn task [] (Thread/sleep 10))

(defn slow
  []
  (newline) (prn :slow)
  (doseq [i (range 100)]
    (task)))

(defn fast
  []
  (newline) (prn :fast)
  (pool/pdoseq 8 [i (range 100)]
    (task)))

(verify
  (time (slow))
  (time (fast)))
```

with results:

```
time (clojure -X:test)

Running tests in #{"test"}

Testing tst._bootstrap

------------------------------------------
   Clojure 1.12.0-alpha3    Java 20.0.1
------------------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core

:slow
"Elapsed time: 1012.908212 msecs"

:fast
"Elapsed time: 137.932203 msecs"

Ran 2 tests containing 0 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
  36.50s user 0.85s system 284% cpu 13.150 total
```

So we see an 8x speedup by using 1 thread on each cpu core (i.e. the `8` after `pdoseq`).  For I/O dominated workloads, you could benefit by using many more threads (eg 64).

Built using [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).